# WPF ToggleButton to look like normal button

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Is there a easy way to make ToggleButton to appear as a normal button? I am trying to click the button and it will trigger IsEnabled to false to another control. With ToggleButton, I can do a trigger on IsChecked property. However the ToggleButton appears quite different when it is toggled. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the WPF designer, right click the ToggleButton in question and select `Edit Template -> Edit a Copy`. Pick the appropriate settings and click OK.

The default template for the ToggleButton will be added to your XAML. In there, delete this code:

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
</Trigger>
```

You can reuse this style/template for multiple ToggleButtons.

**EDIT**

You have another option at your disposal. Use a standard `Button` and wire up the `Click` event handler or a `Command` binding that executes code to update your `IsChecked` property, e.g.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" IsEnabled="False" Content="State" />
<Button Content="Toggle" Command="{Binding ToggleStateCommand}" />
```

Then, of course, your command merely has to execute

```
IsChecked = !IsChecked
```

This all assumes you have an `ICommand` implementation you're comfortable with and that you're somewhat doing MVVM, but perhaps that's a bit out of scope for this Q/A.

Comment: Thanks. is there an easy way to do it? Don't want to duplicate the style code from Button.

Comment: It's "easy" and the "duplication" -- if you can call it that -- is minimal. The template just uses a custom `ButtonChrome` object that has the appropriate styling from the current Windows theme applied. This is the only type of "duplication" that I would ever advocate. That said, your enthusiasm for limiting abuse is a good one to have.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to make `ToggleButton` transparent, and show some other control as it's content. Set `IsHitTestVisible = False` for the content.

Experiment with Margin value too.

```
<ToggleButton Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <Button Content="Toggle Button" Margin="-5" IsHitTestVisible="True" />
</ToggleButton>
```

Above can be customized to use ToggleButton's Content like :

```
<ToggleButton Content="Toggle Button" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Canvas.Left="233" Canvas.Top="158">
    <ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.ContentTemplate>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: this solution disabled the animation when hover over the button

Comment: @Helic You can shift the animation down to internal Button. If you post your animation code, I can modify my answer.